# Why Amazon SES does not deliver email, though sendEmail return success?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, vapor

Using SotoSESV2 in a Vapor project: https://github.com/soto-project/soto.git

Following method return success, but email is clearly not delivered hours after the success, how is it possible?

```swift
return ses.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest).flatMapAlways { re in
    print(re)
    fflush(stdout)
    switch re {
    case .success:
        print("Welcome message sent to: \(emailTo)")
```

Email is not in Junk either.

I do not see any bouncing in AWS dashboard or something.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Pkt.jpg)

Comment: The email may end up in quarantine at the receiver.

Comment: What you mean quarantine? It is not in Junk.

Comment: What is the return code of the mail? Is it 250 OK? Also you can put detailed logging for ses in s3 following https://geko.cloud/en/aws-logs-to-opensearch-via-kinesis/. Change opensearch to s3 in firehose and check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-smtp.html for the codes for debugging.

Comment: Quarantine is like the junk folder but for the email domain. If you send you mail to gmail or something common it is not likely to end up where but say that you send it to a company owned email domain it can have stricter rules on what it let trough. I have had that issue once.

Comment: In my case domain is gmail, still email is not delivered.